# Deleting everything after the second occurrence of a number

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question, if I want to delete everything after the second occurrence of a number:

i.e -

I have:

```
         1105 Bracket Ave. Suite 531 Touche 
         5201 Used St. 1351 Bored Today
```

I want:

```
         1105 Bracket Ave. Suite 531
         5201 Used St. 1351
```

is there a simple formula or VBA I would use for this?

Comment: Another way to approach this is too look at that pattern. Is it always `Number [space] Text [space] Text [space] Text [space] Number` that you want to keep?

Comment: Will there always be a second set of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UDF using VBA's regular expression engine to remove all after the second integer.

```
Option Explicit
Function FirstTwoNumbers(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "(\d+\D+\d+).*"
    FirstTwoNumbers = .Replace(S, "$1")
End With
End Function
```

If there is only a single integer, it will return the entire string.
If the numbers might be decimal numbers, will need to modify `.Pattern`

And here is another UDF using only native VBA methods:

```
Function FirstTwo(S As String) As String
    Dim V
    Dim tS As String
    Dim I As Long, numNumbers As Long

V = Split(S)
Do Until numNumbers = 2
    tS = tS & Space(1) & V(I)
    I = I + 1
    If IsNumeric(V(I - 1)) Then numNumbers = numNumbers + 1
Loop

FirstTwo = Mid(tS, 2)

End Function
```

and finally, a formula with no particular assumptions:

```
 =LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(-TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))),seq))))
```

`seq` and `seq99` are Named Formulas `Formula ► Define Name`

```
seq Refers to:      =ROW(INDEX($1:$255,1,1):INDEX($1:$255,255,1))
seq_99 Refers to:   =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$255,1,1):INDEX($1:$255,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$255,1,1):INDEX($1:$255,255,1))-1)*99)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is with these assumptions:-

1. First occurrence of a number will not have a length > 10
2. There will atleast a distance of 10 or 10 alphabets including spaces between first and second number
3. There will always be a 'space' existing after second number
4. There will always be a second number present in the string

Try this:-

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789",MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+10)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA approach, amend range to suit. It puts the answer in the adjacent column

```
Sub x()

Dim oMatches As Object, r As Range

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d+"
     For Each r In Range("A1:A5")
        If .Test(r) Then
            Set oMatches = .Execute(r)
            If oMatches.Count > 1 Then
                r.Offset(, 1).Value = Left(r, oMatches(1).firstindex + oMatches(1).Length)
            Else
                r.Offset(, 1).Value = r.Value
            End If
        Else
            r.Offset(, 1).Value = r.Value
        End If
     Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula,if A1 is your string,in B1 write:

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX(IFERROR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),0)))
```

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time Array Formula
This will read the length of the string and return the Maximum place of numbers (last number in the string) and return the Left() string till this number